# Inequality of norm in two cases

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

I am currently trying to understand why the following inequality holds for $d_2>d_1>0$ and $\eta >0$, $x= (0,t)$ or $x=(t,t)$ for $t\geq 0$

$||d-\eta x|| \geq \text{min}\{|d_1|, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}|d_2-d_1|\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the parameter $\eta$ is irrelevant.
Next for $x=(0,t)$
$$\|d-x\|\ge |d_1-x_1|=|d_1|.$$
For $x=(t,t)$ the minimal value of $\|d-x\|$ is attained, when
$t=t_0:={d_1+d_2\over 2},$ because the vector $v=(d_1,d_2)-(t_0,t_0)$ is then orthogonal to the line $(t,t).$ The distance is equal $\|v\|,$ i.e.
$$\sqrt{\left (d_1-{d_1+d_2\over 2}\right )^2+\left (d_2-{d_1+d_2\over 2}\right )^2}={\sqrt{2}\over 2}|d_2-d_1|.$$
The inequality can be  proved also by minimizing the quantity $\|(d_1,d_2)-(t,t)\|^2,$ which reduces to finding the minimum of a quadratic polynomial.